# What is the shortcut to apply code changes in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

When I debug a program in Visual Studio 2017, I can change the code using <kbd>Alt+F10</kbd> without rebuilding the program. How can I do this in Qt Creator?

Answer (score 2):

The feature you describe is available (AFAIK) only in visual studio. It requires cooperation between compiler and debuger while gcc and gdb used by Qt Create by default do not have such an option.